# How to silently insert values into temporary table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a SQL script that needs to set values in a temporary table.

```
-- Beginning of script

DECLARE @codes TABLE(code NVARCHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL)
INSERT @codes VALUES ('ABC'), ('FEGHJ')

-- Many more instructions
-- .....
```

When I execute this in my SQL Server Management Studio, it causes this output :

> (2 row(s) affected)

However, I don't want my users to believe that at this point something has actually been changed in the db.

Can I just prevent the INSERT to output anything ? If yes, how ?

Comment: `SET NOCOUNT ON`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert It works. Turn it into an answer ?

Comment: Do your users routinely use SSMS as their user interface?

Comment: @HABO The 'users' that I'm talking about are my developper colleagues who sometimes have to execute maintenance and other scripts

Comment: And they would get scared if the saw that two rows were affected? ;-)

Comment: @Magnus Well, I think part of my job is to make sure they don't ;) . Especially if the cost is cheap like adding 2 lines in the script. Things could get messy if the script failed and were to insert only parts of the rows that are supposed to be added. Messages like "(2 rows inserted) .... (then later) Some error occured, script aborted" could indeed be distracting enough in checking time. 
They should trust the output of my script. If output says 2 rows were inserted, but weren't actually, that's just kinda mean!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SET NOCOUNT ON` When its turned on the count is not returned

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql) is the Microsoft documentation for it if you fancy a read about it